# jquery - как делать разные действия при кликах по кнопке!

Tags: javascript, jquery

например клик первый по кнопке (`input"button"`) в параграфе напишет "не жми" при в током клике "плис не жми" при третьем "Я сказал не жми"??

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Button!</title>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <style>
  #button {
   height: 50px;
   width: 50px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   border: none;
   background: red;
   border-style: none;
   cursor: pointer;
  }
  input[type="button"]:focus {
   outline : none; 
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="button" id="button">
 <p id="result"></p>
 <script>
 $('#button').click(function() {
   var el = $('#result');
   var cnt = el.data('cnt');
   if (!cnt)
     cnt = 0;
   switch (cnt) {
     case 0: el.text("не жми"); break;
     case 1: el.text("плис не жми"); break;
     case 2: el.text("Я сказал не жми");
   }
   el.data({cnt: cnt + 1});
}

 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: было бы хорошо в вопросе увидеть разметку с вашей кнопкой и параграфом.

Comment: оформите это в вопросе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Записывать" куда-нибудь количество кликов:

js:

```
(function () {
  var click = 0,
      mess  = '';
  $('.click-me').click(function () {
    click++;
    if(click === 1) { mess = 'не жми'; }
    if(click === 2) { mess = 'плис не жми'; }
    if(click === 3) { mess = 'Я сказал не жми'; }
    if(click > 3) { mess = 'не знаю что ещё сказать'; }
    $('.result').html(mess);
  });
})();
```

html:

```
<button class="click-me">Click me!</button>
<div class="result"></div>
```

Этот же код на [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jrQAxz)

Comment: О спасибо Николай вы мой спаситель!!

Comment: На здоровье :) Буду признателен если отметишь как решение ;D

Comment: Вот что получилось как вам? :) ( http://dontclick.co.nf/ )

Comment: А как сделать, что бы после третьего клика сообщения начинали повторяться (как цикл) ?

Answer (score 2):

Вариантов 2: либо каждый раз менять обработчики, либо завести счетчик кликов и по нему ориентироваться

```js
$('#button').click(function() {
  var el = $('#result');
  var cnt = el.data('cnt');
  if (!cnt)
    cnt = 0;
  switch (cnt) {
    case 0: el.text("не жми"); break;
    case 1: el.text("плис не жми"); break;
    case 2: el.text("Я сказал не жми");
  }
  el.data({cnt: cnt + 1});
}:
```

Comment: Мне нужно чтоб если жали на кнопку input(button) в p записивалось ето.

Comment: @Poctuk это необходимо оформить в вопросе

Comment: @Poctuk откорректировал ответ